# My json is appearing as a HTML when parsed (android)

Tags: android, html, json, android-json

I'm trying to parse and get the values from a `URL` with `JSON` format. The format of the `JSON` when the `URL` is used in a browser is shown below:

```
{"CompanyID":"1","Message":"Not active user","Success":"false","UserID":"2"}
```

My `JsonParser` code is shown below:

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
* Created by Fathi on 6/16/2015.
*/
public class JsonParser {
final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static JSONArray jArray = null;
static String result = "";

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // make HTTP request
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        Log.e(TAG, "JSON status code:  " + statusCode);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e(TAG, "JSON string:  " + result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {           
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jArray;
}
```

}

The code I'm using in my activity is as follows:

```
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

    // set your json string url here
    String yourJsonStringUrl = "**MY URL COMES HERE**";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {



        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

            // get json string from url

            JSONArray jsonArray = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);


            // loop through all users
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String Success = c.getString("Success");


                // show the values in our logcat
                Log.e(TAG, "Success: " + Success);


            } } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
```

My Logcat is giving me the following error (I have the HTTP response and the string):

```
06-16 03:50:10.841    2470-2489/iss.voltappinterface E/JsonParser.java﹕ JSON     status code:  200
06-16 03:50:10.911    2470-2489/iss.voltappinterface E/JsonParser.java﹕ JSON string:  <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>n<h2>Object moved to <a href="/voln
06-16 03:50:10.921    2470-2489/iss.voltappinterface E/JsonParser.java﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Object of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I can see that my `JSON` is being processed as `HTML` for some reason, and that is what I don't understand, seeing as it looks perfect in the browser. Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: Check your server endpoint its sending you Html content in response.

Comment: Like Nullbyte says : you aren't getting any JSON at all since you appear to be calling to the wrong address. the server is telling you that the call you're trying to make has moved.

Comment: @NullByte  Thanks for the quick response guys, I'm sorry but how does the call move, if you have any idea, the URL is on a local company server, and I'm not sure how it can simply "move". Thanks again

Comment: @TimothyGroote Same to you :)

Comment: @FathiEid i have no idea. maybe check with the server's administrators. i can't see where it is now either since the reply cuts off at `moved to <a href="/voln`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `content-type` header on your endpoint, it's probably `text/html` and **should be** `application/json`

**Edit** : As @Fathi Eid suggest, you can force the Content-type:

```
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Note that is a fix and you should really consider changing the response content type on the api server and not in the client.

Comment: The Server has Microsoft Visual Studio which containt all the information of the API and such, I checked for "endpoint" and found it in web.config, but it doesn't have "content-type". I'm not very experienced with the server as I didnt make the API, I'm just trying to connect to it. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: you can try to use Postman extensions on Chrome and see on the "headers" tab the content type. If you can't change it or didn't find how to do it, maybe SO or ServerFault is the right place

Comment: Dont know what's wrong with my chrome, getting an error whenever I try to download an extension, I'll try it as soon as I can

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, ended up using these:                                            httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: I've added @FathiEid fix to the answer as it's relevant.